# Using nDCG as torch loss function

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

I implemented a loss based on nDCG, as shown in the following code snippet:

```py
import torch

class NDCGLoss(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, relevance_map):
        super(NDCGLoss, self).__init__()
        self.relevance_map = relevance_map

    def get_relevance(self, queries_ids, docs_ids):
        relevance = torch.empty((queries_ids.shape[0], docs_ids.shape[0]), device=queries_ids.device)
        for i, query_idx in enumerate(queries_ids.tolist()):
            for j, doc_idx in enumerate(docs_ids.tolist()):
                if doc_idx in self.relevance_map[query_idx]:
                    relevance[i, j] = 1.0
                else:
                    relevance[i, j] = 0.0
        return relevance

    def _get_dcg(self, scores, relevances):
        discount = 1.0 / (torch.log2(torch.arange(relevances.shape[-1], device=relevances.device) + 2.0))
        ranking = scores.argsort(descending=True)
        ranked = torch.gather(relevances, dim=-1, index=ranking)
        return torch.sum(discount * ranked, dim=-1)

    def forward(self, query_idx, query_rpr, doc_idx, doc_rpr):

        scores = torch.einsum("ab,cb->ac", query_rpr, doc_rpr)  # inner product
        relevance = self.get_relevance(query_idx, doc_idx)  # ground-truth
        dcg = self._get_dcg(scores, relevance)
        idcg = self._get_dcg(relevance, relevance)
        idcg = torch.where(idcg == 0, 1.0, idcg)
        return -torch.log(
            torch.mean(
                torch.div(dcg, idcg)
            ) + 1e-11
        )
```

The similarity score is computed using the query_rpr and doc_rpr embeddings as the inner product. The query_idx and the doc_idx tensors are used to define the ground-truth relevance based on the stored in relevance_map that indicates which docs are relevant for each query.

However, I am receiving the following error.

```py
RuntimeError: a view of a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.
```

**Test case:**

```py
query_idx = torch.tensor([1,2,3])
query_rpr = torch.rand((3,5), requires_grad=True)

doc_idx = torch.tensor([4,5,6])
doc_rpr = torch.rand((3,5), requires_grad=True )


relevance_map = {
    1: [4,8],
    2: [5,6],
    3: [7,9]
}

loss = NDCGLoss(relevance_map)
output = loss(query_idx, query_rpr, doc_idx, doc_rpr)
output.backward()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-25-94eed013e3fb> in <cell line: 16>()
#      14 loss = NDCGLoss(relevance_map)
#      15 output = loss(query_idx, query_rpr, doc_idx, doc_rpr)
# ---> 16 output.backward()

# 1 frames
# /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/_tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs)
#     490                 inputs=inputs,
#     491             )
# --> 492         torch.autograd.backward(
#     493             self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs
#     494         )

# /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
#     249     # some Python versions print out the first line of a multi-line function
#     250     # calls in the traceback and some print out the last line
# --> 251     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
#     252         tensors,
#     253         grad_tensors_,

# RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is coming from the `get_relevance` function where you do in-place assignment (ie `relevance[i, j] = 1.0`). Looking at your code, are you sure the `relevance` tensor needs `requires_grad=True`? If I'm reading the code correctly, `relevance` is your ground truth value - you shouldn't need to backprop through it.

Comment: Hello @Karl, you are right. The error comes from the assignment `relevance[i, j] = 1.0` or `relevance[i, j] = 0.0`, which is the ground truth, as you clearly understood. However, creating the `relevance` tensor without `requires_grad=True` produces the following error: `RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn`.